# Membership Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have a website where I use C# MVC3 Razor to do it. To authorization and authentication, I use Membership. To authentication, my code works correctly, but to authorization, I can't do it work. I have a rule to "Administrator". How I do it?

**web.config**

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
 <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
      name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

   <system.web>
       <authorization>
            <allow roles="?,*"/>
            <deny users="Administrator" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

**Controller.cs**

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public ActionResult Default()
        {
            if (Session["user"] != null)
                return View();
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information! Is the Default() action redirecting you to the Login action? Have you checked to make sure that Session["user"] is not null? Why are you even checking if Session["user"] is null or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) for authorization.

Either one of the standard ones, or [implement a custom one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

Comment: In my web.config I use it

Comment: @Developer123 - then it should work.  You need to add one or more users to the "Administrator" role, and these users should have access to the actions protected by the `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: I have 4 users to "Administrator" role, but when I use [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")], the page don't open

Comment: Try debugging.  Call an action that isn't protected using the Authorize attribute, while logged in as an Administrator.  Examine the roles associated with your principal.  Check which provider is configured (I see you haven't set the defaultProvider attribute in your roleManager configuration element).